# How to print this specific JSON in a Mat Table?

Tags: json, angular, parsing, mat-table

I have this specific JSON file I'm not allowed to change, which looks like this :

```
{
"computers" : {
        "John" : {
            "version" : "1.42.0",
            "environment" : "Default",
            "platform" : "x64",
            "admin" : "true"
        },
        "Peter" : {
            "version" : "1.43.6",
            "environment" : "Default",
            "platform" : "x64",
            "admin" : "true"
        },
        "Eric" : {
            "version" : "1.43.6",
            "environment" : "Default",
            "platform" : "x64",
            "admin" : "false"
        }
}
```

I use the `JSON.parse()` method to parse the file and I put it into a `MatTableDataSource`.

Problem is, when I need to display it in my `MatTable`, I can't really access it the way I want.

I have a column where I want to display all `version` parameters, so for this I can't say : `this.dataSource.computers.????.version`

Do you guys see where I'm getting at ? Do you have any idea of what I can do differently in order to solve this ?

Looking forward to reading you.

Comment: Do you need the names to be displayed? Eric, Peter, etc?

Comment: Unfortunatly, I do :/

Comment: Ok, each object will have the following properties: version, environment, playform, admin, and... name?

Comment: Yes. "name" would be perfect !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular `mat-table` requires the input data to be in an array. First, we use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to extract the keys, which will contain the list of names. Then, we can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to other values within each key in array format. This is followed by mapping the above array objects with the `name` property from the list of names.

```js
const data = {
  "computers": {
    "John": {
      "version": "1.42.0",
      "environment": "Default",
      "platform": "x64",
      "admin": "true"
    },
    "Peter": {
      "version": "1.43.6",
      "environment": "Default",
      "platform": "x64",
      "admin": "true"
    },
    "Eric": {
      "version": "1.43.6",
      "environment": "Default",
      "platform": "x64",
      "admin": "false"
    }
  }
};

const nameList = Object.keys(data.computers);
const dataList = Object.values(data.computers).map((obj, index) => {
  obj['name'] = nameList[index];
  return obj;
});
console.log(dataList);
```

Comment: Testing this atm

Comment: @Zako yup! It should work fine. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Yeah this will do ! Thank you so much @wentjun !

Comment: I may need to save the changes I made to the JSON file in the future. But since I am not allowed to change the format of the file, I've been trying to go back to the way it was before. No success so far. (I guess the first step would be to split the "name" parameter from the "dataList") The objective would be to call JSON.stringify() once we've been able to revert to the inital format of the object. Could you help me out one last time ?

Comment: @Zako Hmm.. Just to check, using my sample code, are you trying to save `data` or `dataList` into the json file?

Comment: Well I'm using your sample of code to display the data properly and to modify it more easily.  I modifiy the object when it's in the form of "dataList". But then I need to save the file when it's in the form of "data". So I'm trying to save "data" into the file

Comment: ( If I were to save "dataList" into the file directly, the format of the JSON would change unfortunatly, that's why I need to go back to the "data" format )

Comment: Hmmm.. I would recommend you to create a shallow clone of `dataList`, and then use JSON.stringify() on the clone! You know how to do it?

Comment: Not really I'm not really sure what you mean sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192952/discussion-between-wentjun-and-zako).